# How do we transform i^(a/b), gcd(a,b)=1, into the form x+iy as complex number?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I would like to know how do we transform $i^{3/2}$ to $-\sqrt{0.5}+i\sqrt{0.5}$?

Also, is there a generalization for this type of transformation, i.e. how do we transform $i^{a/b}$, $\gcd(a,b)=1,$ into the form $x+iy$ as a complex number?

Thank you ^-^

Answer (score 0):

Euler's identity is $$e^{i\theta}=\cos \theta +i\sin \theta$$
so that
$$e^{ni\theta} = \cos n\theta +i\sin n\theta$$

$$i^{3/2} = (e^{i\pi/2})^{3/2}=e^{3\pi/4}=\cos \frac{3\pi}{4} +i\sin \frac{3\pi}{4}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+i\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.$$

Actually, this is only one of two solutions!

The other solution is:

$$i^{3/2} = (e^{i\pi/2+2\pi i})^{3/2}=-e^{3\pi/4}=-\cos \frac{3\pi}{4} -i\sin \frac{3\pi}{4}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-i\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.$$

In general,

$$i^{a/b} = (e^{i\pi/2 +2k\pi i})^{a/b}, \quad k\in\{\cdots,-1,0,1,2,\cdots\}$$

$$i^{a/b} = e^{i(\frac{a\pi}{2b} +\frac{2k\pi a}{b})}, \quad k\in\{\cdots,-1,0,1,2,\cdots\}$$

$$i^{a/b} \in \{ \cdots, e^{\frac{ai\pi}{2b}}, e^{\frac{5ai\pi}{2b}},e^{\frac{9ai\pi}{2b}},\cdots \}$$

$$i^{a/b} \in \left\{ \cos \frac{a\pi(1+4k)}{2b}+i\sin \frac{a\pi(1+4k)}{2b}\right\}, \quad \quad k\in\{\cdots, -1, 0,1,2,\cdots\}$$